# Sort in-memory list by another in-memory list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is possible to sort an in-memory list by another list (the second list would be a reference data-source or something like this) ?

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

// a list of Data Items, randomly sorted
List<DataItem> dataItems = GetDataItems();

// the sort order data source with the paths in the correct order
IEnumerable<string> sortOrder = new List<string> {
    "A",
    "A.A1",
    "A.A2",
    "A.B1"
};

// is there a way to tell linq to sort the in-memory list of objects
// by the sortOrder "data source"
dataItems = dataItems.OrderBy(p => p.Path == sortOrder).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets assign an index to each item in `sortOrder`:

```
var sortOrderWithIndices = sortOrder.Select((x, i) => new { path = x, index = i });
```

Next, we join the two lists and sort:

```
var dataItemsOrdered =
 from d in dataItems
 join x in sortOrderWithIndices on d.Path equals x.path //pull index by path
 orderby x.index //order by index
 select d;
```

This is how you'd do it in SQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative (and I argue more efficient) approach to the one accepted as answer.

```
List<DataItem> dataItems = GetDataItems();
IDictionary<string, int> sortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
     {"A", int.MaxValue},
     {"A.A1", int.MaxValue-1},
     {"A.A2", int.MaxValue -2},
     {"A.B1", int.MaxValue-3},
};

dataItems.Sort((di1, di2) => sortOrder[di1.Path].CompareTo(sortOrder[di2.Path]));
```

Let's say `Sort()` and `OrderBy()` both take O(n*logn), where *n* is number of items in `dataItems`. The solution given here takes O(n*logn) to perform the sort. We assume the step required to create the dictionary `sortOrder` has a cost not significantly different from creating the `IEnumerable` in the original post.

Doing a `join` and *then* sorting the collection, however adds an additional cost O(nm) where m is number of elements in `sortOrder`. Thus the total time complexity for that solution comes to O(nm + nlogn).

In theory, the approach using `join` may boil down to O(n * (m + logn)) ~= O(n*logn) any way. But in practice, `join` is costing extra cycles. This is in addition to possible extra space complexity incurred in the `linq` approach where auxiliary collections might have been created in order to process the `linq` query.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of paths is large, you would be better off performing your lookups against a dictionary:

```
var sortValues = sortOrder.Select((p, i) => new { Path = p, Value = i })
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Path, x => x.Value);

dataItems = dataItems.OrderBy(di => sortValues[di.Path]).ToList();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Indeed, the list of paths contains about 1,400 items

Answer (score 0):

custom ordering is done by using a custom comparer (an implementation of the IComparer interface) that is passed as the second argument to the OrderBy method.